# Order of fields getting changed in response JSON from a REST API

Tags: java, json, spring-restcontroller

In my RestController I am returning a POJO which has a LinkedHashMap.

```
public class ReportTypesVO {

private LinkedHashMap<Integer,EachReportTypeVO> reportTypes;

public LinkedHashMap<Integer, EachReportTypeVO> getReportTypes() {
    return this.reportTypes;
}

public void setReportTypes(LinkedHashMap<Integer, EachReportTypeVO> reportTypes) {
    this.reportTypes = reportTypes;
}}
```

My API:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/dailyReport", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ReportTypesVO populateDailyReportScreen() throws Exception {
    ReportProcess reportProcessing = new ReportProcess();
    logger.info("populateDailyReportScreen Service reached");
    ReportTypesVO response=reportProcessing.loadReportTypes(ReportProcess.DAILY_REPORT_METADATAID);

    return response;
}
```

In the "loadReportTypes" method I am populating this LinkedHashMap and this map is getting populated in desired order.then after setting this map inside "reportTypesVo" also i can see the entries inside map is in desired order. But when I see the Response JSON the entries inside map is in a different order.
FYI now I am hitting the service with POST MAN.Jre version-7
 Where is the issue ? Is Spring
having some inbuilt functionality to change order in JSON ?

Comment: Can you show us what you see as ordered and the unexpexted response string?

Comment: @bigdestroyer this post suggests to use list in place of Linkedhashmap...But the purpose of linkedhashmap is to preserve the order only